# How to count related items in child list

Tags: 2013, workflow, item

I have two lists (Parrent and Child)

Parrent list (People)
Child list: (Requirements) where is lookup column to People (list)

I need to count related items in chlid list for specified user and place this count number to parrent list item.

It is possible? (Maybe using workflow?)

Thanks a lot.
Dominik Divák

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a number field in Parent list with initial value as 0.
Attach SPD workflow on item created on child list.

When new item is created in child list, get lookup value. Based on lookup value , get the parent item. From parent item, get column count, increment it, and update the item again.

Comment: Thanks Monica. This is exactly im looking for.  Can you describe Workflow procedure. Im not expert in workflow design. Concretely how to design condition of lookup column. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got it. Is there a way how to do workflow for detele item (minus 1) :)

Comment: yes, in workflow you have a step to delete item. But can you clarifiy on which item to delete - parent or child. And I could not get the term "minus 1".